# Retrieving post excerpt as a shortcode

Tags: shortcode, excerpt

How do I register a shortcode to add the **manual** post excerpt anywhere within the same post? Does this shortcode already exist in WP?

Thanks!

Comment: If we want to run this code with the program (Code Snippets), how do we do this?

Comment: @user233657 you shouldn't post questions in the solutions box to other users questions. Code snippets support can help you, but 3rd party plugin questions are offtopic here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add this to your child theme's `functions.php` file:

```
add_shortcode( 'output_post_excerpt', 'get_the_excerpt' );
```

Then use `[output_post_excerpt]`

Comment: That was quick and easy. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Hello. Can this be used with "latest posts" also?